# badimageformatexception - Which assembly is problematic

Tags: .net, nunit

I'm fighting with a BadImageFormatException:

```
System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'Bla.Bla.Bla, Version=0.0.0.18329, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

I'm fairly sure that the Bla.Bla.Bla assembly is correct (set as AnyCpu). It's dependancies are also correct (only Castle.Core, Castle.Windsor and Castle.WcfIntegration). However, when I run the NUnit tests for this project, I get the BadImageFormatException.

Is there a way to find out what assembly is responsible for this exception?

Answer (score 0):

So I turned on the Build warnings and noticed a warning that said "mismatch between processor architecture" on the Bla.Bla.Bla assembly. I checked the PlatformTarget and it was AnyCpu. Just for fun I changed it to x86 and back to AnyCpu and.... It worked!

I then checked the diffs for the .csproj file and noticed that the platformtarget had changed there from Itanium to AnyCpu...

So this might be a bug in Visual Studio where the UI does not show the correct PlatformTarget.

Now can I please get two days of my life back?

UPDATE: my colleague, who created the solution in vs2010, opened it again and she had Itanium in the dropdown. I'm on vs2012 and I don't have Itanium in the dropdown.

**tl;dr: Classic UI bug: selected value is not in the dropdown and the first value is selected.**

Comment: Hmm, no, "Itanium" does not exist as a .NET platform target.

Comment: It doesn't.  That's the entire point of having a jitter, if your program actually runs on an Itanium then you automatically get the jitter for an Itanium.  No additional config is needed for that.  Mixing up a *solution platform* name with the .NET *target platform* setting is a common mistake.  Two very different things.  The solution platform only matters to unmanaged projects.

Comment: Yes, but the solution was accidentally set up to compile for Itanium. We never intended that. The problem is that I could not see that the project was set up for Itanium in vs2012 because the dropdown wrongly showed AnyCpu.